# Converting an interval to duration per hour per weekday in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following problem:

Suppose we have:

```
 Idx        ID      StartTime          EndTime
  1:         1 2014-01-01 02:20:00 2014-01-01 03:42:00
  2:         1 2014-01-01 14:51:00 2014-01-01 16:44:00
```

note: *Idx* is not given, but I'm simply adding it to the table view.

Now we see that person with ID=1 is using the computer from 2:20 to 3:42. Now what I would like to do is to convert this interval into a set of variables representing hour and weekday and the duration in those periods.

```
 Idx        ID Monday-0:00 Monday-1:00 ... Wednesday-2:00 Wednesday-3:00
  1:         1                                  40             42
```

For the second row we would have

```
 Idx        ID Monday-0:00 Monday-1:00 ... Wednesday-14:00 Wednesday-15:00  Wednesday-16:00
  2:         1                                  9             60                  44
```

Now the problem is of course that it can span over multiple hours as you can see from the second row.

I would like to do this **per row** and I was wondering if this is possible without too much computational effort and using data.table?

PS: it is also possible that the interval spans over the day.

Comment: Are you looking to create a data set with 168 columns? Not sure how you going to use it.

Comment: That is correct, I actually would like to do a simple regression determining which of the weekday-time variable are relevant for example of having kids. So Y=kids (dummy) and then the predictors are the 168 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
#produce sample data
DT<-data.table(idx=1:100,ID=rep(1:20,5), StartTime=runif(100,60*60,60*60*365)+ymd('2014-01-01'))
DT[,EndTime:=StartTime+runif(1,60,60*60*8)]

#make fake start and end dates with same day of week and time but all within a single calendar week
DT[,fakestart:=as.numeric(difftime(StartTime,ymd('1970-01-01'),units="days"))%%7*60*60*24+ymd('1970-01-01')]
DT[,fakeend:=as.numeric(difftime(EndTime,ymd('1970-01-01'),units="days"))%%7*60*60*24+ymd('1970-01-01')]
setkey(DT,fakestart,fakeend)
#check that weekdays line up
nrow(DT[weekdays(EndTime)==weekdays(fakeend)])
nrow(DT[weekdays(StartTime)==weekdays(fakestart)])
#both are 100 so we're good.

#check that fakeend > fakestart
DT[fakeend<fakestart]
#uh-oh some ends are earlier than starts, let's add 7 days to those ends
DT[fakeend<fakestart,fakeend:=fakeend+days(7)]


#make data.table with all possible labels
DTin<-data.table(start=seq(from=ymd('1970-01-01'),to=DT[,floor_date(max(fakeend),"hour")],by=as.difftime(hours(1))))
DTin[,end:=start+hours(1)]
DTin[,label:=paste0(format(start,format="%A-%H:00"),' ',format(end,format="%A-%H:00"))]

#set key and use new foverlaps feature of data.table which merges by interval
setkey(DT,fakestart,fakeend)
setkey(DTin,start,end)
DTout<-foverlaps(DT,DTin,type="any")

#compute duration in each interval
DTout[,dur:=60-pmax(0,difftime(fakestart,start,unit="mins"))-pmax(0,difftime(end,fakeend,unit="mins"))]

#cast all the rows up to columns for final result
castout<-dcast.data.table(DTout,idx+ID~label,value.var="dur",fill=0)
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is simply brilliant. Thanks!